# Froebenius distance matrix of Matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have two sets of matrices Sigma and Sigma_barre (size: KxDxD) and I try to compute the Frobenius distance (2-Norm on matrix) matrix between these two sets, that is to say, a matrix M (size KxK) such that

M[ i , j ] = distance between Sigma[ i ] and Sigma_barre[ j ]

I used np.linalg.norm but I am not a hundred per cent sure it does what I want. Here is my naive code :

```
M = np.zeros((K,K))
for i in range(K):
    for j in range(K):
        M[i,j] = np.linalg.norm(sigma[i]-sigma_barre[j])
```

So my question is: do you know an elegant/efficient way to compute this matrix?

Comment: Reshape both to 2D and use [`cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) : `cdist(sigma.reshape(sigma.shape[0],-1),sigma_barre.reshape(sigma_barre.shape[0],-1))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one go by adding some dummy dimensions and specifying which axis the summation should be done over.

```
M = np.linalg.norm(sigma[:,None] - sigma_barre[None,:], axis=(2,3))
```

Since `sigma[:,None] - sigma_barre[None,:]` is a KxKxDxD sized matrix, this can take up a lot of memory depending on how big K and D is. If memory is an issue, your solution seems good, although you can loop `j` starting from `i+1` instead, since you know that `M[i,j] == M[j,i]`, and that `M[i,i] == 0`.